# Java API: Как достать LinkedHashMap из List

Tags: java, rest, test-automation, linked-list

Пишу тест для **REST API**, юзаю **restassured** и **jackson**
Описал модель **JSON** респонса в классах, но есть одно но, т.к. приходит массив объектов

```
[{some objects},
{some objects},
....
{some objects}]
```

то и принимаю его в `List<Object>`
и здесь проблема с десериализацией,

```
List<Country> countries = given().spec(spec)
                .expect()
                .statusCode(200)
                .when()
                .get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/")
                .thenReturn().as(List.class);
```

я десериализую классом `List.class` но он все складывает в `LinkedHashMap`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не как вытянуть значения из countries и добраться до key/value

Comment: вы ни как не сможете, такое коде не работает

Comment: Подскажите куда копать в такой ситуации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
.get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/").as(Country[].class);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все полетело.